# Connecting multiple led strips in parallel with arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, rtc, led-strip

I am making a led panel using led strips. Each of the two led strips are 5M long containing 300 LED SMD Striplights. I have cut each of the 2 strips into many small strips of lengths of about 38 cm and connected them in parallel i.e there is  a singe pair of terminals for all the strips.I have a 12V,5A power supply. I had tried to drive the panel using Arduino Mega in combination with a MOSFET as is it is commonly done for a single led strip but I am unable to make it work.
Can anybody please help me out?

Other components being used are - PIR sensor , RTC module

Comment: Not enough info. Did you cut these strips only at the cut points? Have you tested them separately? Are they meant to run on 12? Will the MOSFET drive a single, uncut strip? What's the total power requirement for all of your strips? (Add the current requirements of the individual strips together)

Comment: If you are using a mosfet like IR**F**Z44N you should change that to a logic level IR**L**Z44N. Arduino 5V isn't enough for a normal mosfet to allow enough current pass through.

Comment: One LED strip is lots of little LED strips in parallel. One LED strip cut into sections and wired in parallel is no different to one LED strip.

Comment: If you can wire up the power to work for a single string, you should be able to "star" wire from the output side to all the other LED strips and have it still work. Star wiring is to wire the strip directly to the PSU, instead of running a common power from one strip to the next. It handles current/heat and spikes better.

Comment: Post a schematic of your circuit. Post all the specifications of your LEDs.What do you mean you can't it to work, which part?